# Determining the Broadband connection type or 'last mile' of internet connection from a computer

Tags: c#, telecommunication, broadband

I was wondering if it is possible to determine the type of broadband connection being used from a computer? Whether it is being provided via ADSL or Cable, etc.

I have tried to achieve this programmatically in C#, this is my findings thus far:

- **Network Interface Class** and **IPv4InterfaceStatistics** Class: These can provide me with pieces of information such as all the network interfaces available on a machine, the speed of an interface and the current download and upload rates (through calculation).
- **Communicating with a router / modem**: It is possible to communicate with a router or modem through HTTP requests, but it is difficult due to the variations between models and manufacturers. Also information provided by routers and modems pertains mostly their configuration - attached devices, static routes, blocked keywords and services.
- **Local and Public IP:** I can retrieve the local IP using the **IPHostEntry** Class and the public IP from making a web request.

None of these pieces of information can tell me the Broadband connection type, but I might be able to guess using all these pieces of information (heuristics).

Is it possible to determine the Broadband connection type from a connected computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the service provider from sites like http://whoismyisp.org.  You could then compare that to a lookup table.

Comment: Thanks! these are good pieces of information to potentially incorporate that I hadn't considered. Not sure how I would populate the connection types corresponding to the ISP or hostname? Some ISPs offer more than one type of broadband too

Answer (score 0):

I think its difficult to know connection type programmatically. But anyway you can refer below link for your information and give it a try.

[How to retrieve connection details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452991.aspx)

In above link you will find information about ConnectionProfile which provides information about established connection. To get ConnectionProfile you have to use NetworkInformation static class.

Hope you will find this info helpful.